# Como criar checkbox dinamicas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

Estou usando os seguintes comandos para criar as checkbox

```
 if (isset($finded_documents)) {
                      // inicia a variável que vai guardar os checkboxes
                      $checkboxes = '';

                      // para cada documento encontrado
                      foreach ($finded_documents as $check) {
                        // acrescenta um Checkbox
                        $checkboxes .= '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">'
                          . "<input id='check-$check[id]' type='checkbox' value='$check[id]' name='docs[]' class='custom-control-input'> "
                          . "<label class='custom-control-label' for='check-$check[id]'>$check[Nome_Documento]</label>"
                          . '</div>';

                      }
                      // mostra os $checkboxes na tela
                      echo $checkboxes;
                    }

                  ?>
```

Gostaria que quando eu clicasse em uma checkbox, adicionaria essa linha de comando:

```
<input type="date" name="data" placeholder="Digite a data do Vencimento"
                           class="form-control"><br>
```

Comment: Você não poderia deixar o input de data já criado oculto, e então exibir ele conforme um dos checkbox forem marcados?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer desta forma usando JS puro:

HTML:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="id_checkbox">
  <p>Digite a data:</p>
  <input id="id_data" name="data" placeholder="Digite a data do Vencimento" type="hidden">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('id_checkbox').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('id_data').removeAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    document.getElementById('id_data').setAttribute('type', 'date')
  } else
    document.getElementById('id_data').setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
});
```

Espero que atenda ao que precisa.

Comment: atende mais ou menos mano, esse script funciona com checkbox determinadas ja, e nao igual ao meu codigo, onde as checkbox sao geradas dependendo da quantidade registrada.

Comment: @NattanAfonso, você pode inserir a id das checkbox automaticamente conforme elas são criadas, simplesmente atribua o nome do id da checkbox, e coloque a variável dentro dos parenteses do `document.getElementById(var)`. Se forem muitas, coloque o nome delas num array, e se refira à posição do array iterando sobre o mesmo. Se quiser edito um exemplo pra você.